# join to all rows of a table even without values sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have a date table that I use to determine week of the year (our year is not calendar year based right now.).  I have a union query that creates a table that I am going to use in a table valued function.  I can create the table in the union query but it only produces the 40 weeks that have actual data.  I need it to show the weeks regardless of whether data exists or not.
I have tried to left outer join on the week table but I still get only records where the week has data associated with it.

```
    left outer join [dbo].[LOOKUP_WEEK_NUMBER] w on
(p.[Program_Year_ID] = w.[Program_Year_Nbr]) and
(p.[Installation_Complete_Date] between w.[Week_Start] and w.[Week_End])
```

LOOKUP_WEEK_NUMBER table has all the weeks of the year and a start and end date for each week.  The p table contains the project data.  What I am doing is bucketing the projects into weeks for reporting purposes.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text.

Comment: try using a `RIGHT JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 0):

change to a `left join` from your lookup table instead of to your lookup table, or use a `right join` to your lookup table.

```
from  [dbo].[LOOKUP_WEEK_NUMBER] w
  left join ... p 
    on (p.[Program_Year_ID] = w.[Program_Year_Nbr])
   and (p.[Installation_Complete_Date] between w.[Week_Start] and w.[Week_End])
```